# Menu not showing list results

Tags: c#, arrays, list, menu

I have this code that runs a menu but its not showing the list information.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Teste_Menu
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Menu();
            List<Modelo> ListaModelo = new List<Modelo>();
            ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "Civic", 180, 29000));
            ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "Jazz", 100, 15000));
            ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "HRV", 115, 22500));



        }

        static void Menu()
        {
            string escolha;

            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;

                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine(" ==================================================================================================== ");
                Console.WriteLine(" =========================================== Carros ================================================= ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ==================================================================================================== \n\n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine(" * Consultar Lista de Carros -----------------------------------------------> (1)\n  ");


                escolha = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (escolha)
                {
                    case "1": ListaModelo();
                    break;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();

        }
        while (escolha != "2");
        }

        static void ListaModelo()
        {
             {
                 var ListaModelo = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 3));

                 ListaModelo.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
             }
        }

    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I press 1 the menu is not showing the car list. It just prints:

```
1
2
3
4
```

And no names. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well when you press `1` the method `ListaModelo()` is called and it creates a new list of `int` and then prints them all and the actual output is
`0 1 2`
You should rather make `ListaModelo` a class variable, then assign items in `Main()` and then just write output in `ListaModelo()` without overwriting your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create in your method `ListaModelo` a completely new list named `ListaModelo` which is filled only with numbers. Although it has the same name, it is not the same List as the one which you instantiated in you `Main` method in this line:

```
List<Modelo> ListaModelo = new List<Modelo>();
```

One of the things you could do to solve your problem is to put the declaration of the List outside of the `Main` method and make it `static` :

```
class Program
{

    public static List<Modelo> ListaModelo = new List<Modelo>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
```

and remove the line in your `ListaModelo()` method :

```
var ListaModelo = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 3));
```

To have a meaningful output you need to override the `ToString` method in the `Modelo` class. So it will display all the properties that you would like to see. Insert this method into your `Modelo` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", yourProperty1, yourProperty2, yourProperty3, yourProperty4);
}
```

Also please make sure that the name of the method to print and the name of the List `ListaModelo` are different.

One last point! you need to fill your list with cars before showing the `Menu` otherwise it will be empty! Just switch the order to:

```
List<Modelo> ListaModelo = new List<Modelo>();
ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "Civic", 180, 29000));
ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "Jazz", 100, 15000));
ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "HRV", 115, 22500));

Menu();
```

Comment: I did that but Im getting this error - Error 2 Ambiguity between 'Teste_Menu.Program.ListaModelo' and 'Teste_Menu.Program.ListaModelo()'

Comment: @Dany4k you need to change one of them. The compiler cannot distinguish. Image you would say the word "apple" to the fruit and the same word for meaning "to eat an apple" how would you distinguish?

Comment: Like using ListaModelo1 on the menu and keep ListaModelo for the lists?

Comment: @Dany4k yes exactly, or give the method a little more meaningful name like `printCarInformation()` or `ConsultarListaDeCarros()`

Comment: @Dany4k one last point, you need to switch the order of showing the menu and filling the list. Have a look at the last lines of my answer, I made an edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and help! I did exactly as you said and added the Menu (); in the end but when I press 1 nothing shows..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144958/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-dany4k).

Comment: @Dany4k you need to override the `ToString()` method. I made an edit to show you how. also have a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to write the car list, you should have have a argument in Menu function:

   static void Menu(List param)

   2. In ListaModelo same problem, you should have List as argument:
   3. Then you can have ListaModelo function like this:

      static void ListaModelo(List param)
           {

      ```
              param.ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x.Name));

       }
      ```